# How to create a global method and use it

Tags: javascript

im trying to make a method that returns either the `attachEvent` function or the `addEventListener` function.
im also trying to make it a global method so it could be used in the following manner: `Element.eventMethod("event",function(){});`

im also want to be able to attach multiple events, which is what im using the for loop for.

```
    var functions = {
    "addEvents" : function(e,o,f){
        if(!window.eventMethod){
            if(typeof addEventListener !== "function"){
                if(typeof attachEvent !== "function"){
                    //ie8
                }else{
                    window.eventMethod = function(){
                        return attachEvent;
                    };
                }
            }else{
                window.eventMethod = function(){
                    return addEventListener;
                };
            }
        }
        var r = e.split(",");
        for(var i=0;i<r.length;i++){
            o.eventMethod(e[i],f);
        }
    }
};
```

the method is called using the following code
`functions.addEvents(events,object,fu);`

however, im getting the "Cannot set property 'eventMethod' of undefined" error.

what am i doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: Looks like window is not defined in the given codeblock? or maybe it is the "o.eventMethod" call :) should point out where the error is located in your code

Comment: @TylerNichols `window` is the Global object. It is always defined.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Gotcha. Still, they should point out where the error is occuring in the code

Comment: You need to show us the actual code you are using to invoke your function that is causing the error. Where are `events`, `object` and `fu` getting their values from?

Comment: See my updated answer below for an explanation of the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code, I get a different error. The error is on this line:

```
o.eventMethod(e[i],f)
```

Which is where you are trying to call `eventMethod` on the object that needs to get wired up to the event. Since you are not establishing `eventMethod` as a property of that object, the code fails.

Now, I think you were hoping that `eventMethod()` would run and return the right actual method, which would then be called on `o`, but that's not what that syntax does. Instead, you need to pass the desired method name (as a string) into `o` and then, after that method is resolved, you pass it the arguments it needs.

```js
var functions = {
    addEvents : function(e,o,f) {
    
       // No need to set up window.eventMethod twice. Just get the right
       // method reference...
       var m = null; 
       // But, you need to set it to the string name of the function, not the function itself
       m = (window.addEventListener) ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
     
       // ... And then use that reference in the single method wrapper:
       window.eventMethod = function(){
         return m;
       };

       // Split the event string into an array and loop through the array   
      e.split(",").forEach(function(evt){
         // Invoke the right method by passing the string name of the method into the
         // object and then passing the arguments to that method.
         o[eventMethod()](evt.trim(), fu);
      });
   }
};

var events = "click, mouseover, mouseout";
var object = document.querySelector("div");
var fu = function(evt){ 
  console.log("The " + evt.type + " event has fired."); 
};
functions.addEvents(events,object,fu);
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Now, to ensure that this can be available globally, but not collide with any other `eventMethod` global variable, you should encapsulate your code in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) and after the function declaration, you'd expose the function as a property of the Global object, but via a custom namespace:

```
(function(){
  var functions = {
    addEvents : function(e,o,f) {

       // No need to set up window.eventMethod twice. Just get the right
       // method reference...
       var m = null; 
       // But, you need to set it to the string name of the function, not the function itself
       m = (window.addEventListener) ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";

       // ... And then use that reference in the single method wrapper:
       window.eventMethod = function(){
         return m;
       };

       // Split the event string into an array and loop through the array   
      e.split(",").forEach(function(evt){
         // Invoke the right method by passing the string name of the method into the
         // object and then passing the arguments to that method.
         o[eventMethod()](evt, fu);
      });
   }
  };

    // Create a custom namespace object on the Global object:
    window.MyUtilities = {};

    // Attach the function to that object:
    window.MyUtilities.functions = functions;
})();
```

Now, you have a cross-browser wrapper function that is available globally like this:

```
window.MyUtilities.functions.addEvents(events,object,fu);
```

Comment: i tried to eliminate the need to check which event listener function should be used everytime i want to add a listener. could you maybe point out why my way isnt working?

Comment: @Alex But why? The overhead for that check is absolutely minuscule and I can guarantee that the simplicity of my code makes it much more efficient than yours. Your code also makes incorrect assumptions like: `if(typeof attachEvent !== "function"){  //ie8  }`. If `attachEvent` is not a function, then the browser is **not** IE8, it's virtually every other browser except for IE8. IE8 absolutely did have `attachEvent`. Also, there's no need to use `typeof`, just check for the existence of the function as I've done in my code.

Comment: @Alex Also, your if/then logic is unnecessarily deep. Once you know that `addEventListener` isn't supported, you can assume that it must support `attachEvent` because that is the only option (unless you want to support browsers from 1998).